# Items randomly never reach pipeline when iterating over a list

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm fairly new to scrapy. I'm crawling a site that offers a list of websites. I want to crawl certain pages of those websites.

Example: siteX.com has the following list:

```
http://siteA.com
http://siteB.com
http://siteC.com
```

All those pages have sub-sites following the same structure, I need two additional requests per site to get their data:

```
http://siteA.com/test/1
http://siteA.com/test/2
http://siteB.com/test/1
http://siteB.com/test/2
http://siteC.com/test/1
http://siteC.com/test/2
```

I'm able to achieve that **with a single entry** with the following code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    entry = response.css("list").extract()[0]
    details_page_link = prefix + entry
    request = scrapy.Request(details_page_link, callback=self.parse_subpage)
    request.meta["foo"] = foo
    yield request

def parse_subpage(self, response):
    foo = response.meta["foo"]
    foo["more"] = response.css("more").extract_first()

    link_to_sub_page = response.css("link").extract_first() 
    request = scrapy.Request(link_to_sub_page, callback=self.parse_sub_sub_page)

    request.meta["foo"] = foo
    yield request

def parse_sub_subpage(self, response):
    foo = response.meta["foo"]
    foo["fina"] = response.css("something").extract_first()
    yield foo
```

Foo is then being put into a database in the pipeline. My problem now is that **when I iterate over the list on the source website, not all the items make it into the pipeline**:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for entry in response.css("div.container tbody 
        a::attr(href)").extract():
            details_page_link = prefix + entry
            request = scrapy.Request(details_page_link, callback=self.parse_subpage)
            request.meta["foo"] = foo
            yield request
```

It's totally random though - it's not always the same sites and I don't see any errors in the logs ("LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG"). But crawling single sites always works. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: maybe because you only extract first?

Comment: No, it's actually always more than one result.

Comment: what is `list` in `for entry in list:` where is it coming from

Comment: @Umair: I updated the code above. I'm basically iterating over every link to a website in that given list on the source site.

Comment: @user3255061 Hah, just do `div.container a::attr(href)` instead of  `div.container tbody a::attr(href)`

Comment: No, doesn't work either. I think this part of the code works, I can see all the right urls being extracted. Appreciate your help though!